# Includes association with conditions

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, associations

I am trying to include this association

```
class Moment < ActiveRecord::Base

has_many :user_taggings_excluded_creator, class_name: "UserTagging", conditions: proc {["user_id != ?", self.created_by]}
```

It's working when I try to write it on the terminal but when I use `includes` the procedure is not working at all.

I have this error when I try to call my controller with `user_taggings_excluded_creator`association.

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `created_by' for #<ActiveRecord::Relation::ActiveRecord_Relation_UserTagging:0x0000010548b920>:
```

**Edit :** It seems that `self` is not my class `Moment` but the class calling this association.

I have no idea of what's happening. Does anyone have some ?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling you that the attribute `created_by` does not exists on the instance of the class `UserTagging`.

Look into your `db/schema.rb` file to check if the attribute exists or not.

Comment: It seems strange because `self` refers to another class. I don't understand why it's working on the console but not when I call it from an `includes`.
I've just updated the code to show which class is `self`.